# Extend ControlValueAccessor with isEmpty function

Tags: angular, forms, angular-reactive-forms, controlvalueaccessor

i have a parent form with all subforms that implements `ControlValueAccessor` interface.
I need then to validate the emptiness of these forms from the parent. The logic of the `isEmpty` changes in each form.
I tried to extend the interface `ControlValueAccessor` with an `isEmpty` method, but what i see from the parent form are only standard `FormControl` childs without the `isEmpty` method.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: implements Validator, you can take a look e.g. to https://netbasal.com/adding-integrated-validation-to-custom-form-controls-in-angular-dc55e49639ae

Comment: you mean, i can add a validator and check the isEmpty error on the parent form change?

Comment: yes, if you create a provider and a function validate, your FormControl becomes valid or not according this function (and if you add anothers validators according this validators too)

Answer (score 0):

I mean that you need add as provider

```
providers: [
    {
      provide: NG_VALIDATORS,
      useExisting: YourComponent,
      multi: true
    }
  ]
```

And create a function validate

```
validate({ value }: FormControl) {
    ....
    return isNotValid?{invalid: true}:null
  }
```

Inside the custom Form Control. Then the control is invalid according this function validate independently you create the formControl with validators or not